# Convert following jquery code to javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jquery code

```
$(this).blur(function () {
    name_valid(recordid);
});
```

I want this jquery code to be converted to core js code.

I also dont want to change anything in the first_name field and add onblur event.

Can I just with javascript and no html convert this jquery to js.

Comment: Yes, jQuery **is** JavaScript.

Comment: I already mentioned i cant change html code.Can only take its id and perform js functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
/* Use your id of link or button etc. here */
var linkid = document.getElementById("link");

linkid.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
  name_valid(recordid);
}, true);
```

You can read more about blur [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur)